# Почему в русском языке столько правил орфографии?

Tags: орфография

Если взять белоруcский, который ближе к старославянскому, то там правило одно — как слышится, так и пишется. Зачем русский язык так запутали?

Comment: Ответ не заставит себя ждать, если исправить грамматику, синтаксис и смысл Вопроса.

Comment: Опять эти националистические бредни: "ближе к старославянскому", "второй по благозвучности после итальянского" (правда это украинцы так говорят про свой) и так далее и тому подобное.

Answer (score 5):

Русское письмо фонематическое (смысловое), а не фонетическое (звуковое). **А что это значит?**

Это значит, что на письме отражается   не только фонетика слова (как оно слышится), но и его значение. Например, в словах "лес - леса - лесник - лесной" мы всегда пишем корень ЛЕС, передающий смысл этого слова, хотя говорим "л(и)сной", тем самым отличая корень ЛЕС от других корней (например, от корня  ЛИС в слове "лиса"). Поэтому нам легко понимать грамотно написанный текст.

**Но зачем мы меняем гласные, почему говорим "л(и)сной"?** Дело в том, что гласные И, А более удобны для произношения, чем гласные Е, О, так как обеспечивают плавность, красоту речи, а также ее меньшие энергозатраты. Такое произношение соответствует орфоэпическим нормам русского языка.

Comment: >> *Но зачем мы меняем гласные, почему говорим "л(и)сной"? Дело в том, что гласные И, А более удобны для произношения... *Наука объяснила, почему опиум заставляет спать. Дело в том, что в нём заключена снотворная сила. ©

Comment: А вы, Niemand, зачем редуцируете гласные в безударных слогах? Говорили бы, как пишете, и никаких проблем, как и в белорусском языке.

Comment: Северные диалекты с  их эканьем и оканьем требуют гораздо меньше энергии в артикуляции, чем московское произношение с его широко растягиваемыми во все стороны губами, но нормой является именно последнее.

Comment: При произношении звука А язык находится в нейтральном положении, а при произношении О язык сдвигается назад, звук  лабиализованный (огубленный). А вообще-то интересно было бы сравнить гласные по их напряженности, по силовым затратам при артикуляции.

Comment: >> *А вы, Niemand...*   Ну, мне так удобнее. Но я, тем не менее, не считаю, что это удовлетворительное объяснение. Оно задним числом.

Comment: @Vera например, вологодским говором можно говорить вообще почти не размыкая губ, в то время как яркое московское [а] требует от говорящего значительных усилий.

Comment: Интересное мнение. Жаль, что никто ещё не хочет высказаться на эту тему.

Comment: На «эту тему»? Какую тему? В вопросе неграмотного, запутавшегося в русском языке, что-то говорится о правилах. А у вас ни слова об этом.

Comment: Кажется, человек сказал, что ему трудно дается русский язык, попросил извинения за ошибки. Этого вполне достаточно, чтобы отнестись к нему с уважением и попробовать объяснить то, что ему непонятно. (Вы же , к сожалению, этого объяснения не поняли, а вопрос действительно интересный для всех нас). Что касается "темы", то здесь речь идет о фонетике: какие звуки более удобны для произношения, в чем причина того, что мы в безударной позиции предпочитаем звуки А и И звукам О и Е. И вывод: давайте будем добрее и вежливее к людям, которые посещают наш форум, потому что это наши гости.

Comment: В вопросе — о правилах и их избытке. Вы же по-доброму лесом гостя послали.

Comment: Вам так показалось. Есть такой термин, как "орфографическое чтение". Если выговаривать каждый гласный и согласный, то от правил останется мало что (шипящие, разделительные знаки да форма написания слов). Вот тогда в русском языке не будет "столько правил". Надеюсь, что мой ответ понятен и гостю, и ВАМ.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что современная белорусская орфография была создана относительно недавно. И создана, можно сказать, заново. А русское правописание отражает более старое произношение. Менять кардинально правописание никто сейчас не будет - это слишком накладно, хотя и было несколько реформ, в частности в 1918 году, (когда откинули яти и твердые знаки и другие изменения).

Answer (score 0):

Любой "старый" язык имеет множество правил орфографии. Что-то сложилось исторически, что-то является наследием ныне не используемых слов или букв. Во французском, например, зачастую из семи букв читаются всего четыре. Про английский с его десятками времён глаголов вообще лучше скромно умолчим... Некоторые языки постсоветского пространства были искусственно упрощены грамматически. Например, многие азиатские республики использовали кириллицу для письма и там уж всяко - как слышали, так и писали. Белорусский язык не исключение.

Comment: "английский с его десятками времён глаголов" - широко распространенный миф советского времени (бонк-бонк-бонк)

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, орфография русского языка довольно проста и логична. 95% процентов написаний русских слов основаны на одном-единственном морфологическом принципе. Это  принцип, суть которого состоит в том, что каждая морфема (приставка, корень, суффикс, окончание) **пишется одинаково** несмотря на то, что в разных словах может произноситься по-разному.

Например, есть правило написания сочетания букв "оло". По этому правилу мы пишем слово "молоко", хотя произносим его как "малако". Кто-то может возразить, ну почему мы не можем просто писать слово молоко как "малако".
Проблема в том, что есть много слов с этим корнем, где буква "о" не редуцированна в "а", например "золото", "колос", "молот".

Таким образом, если писать корень "оло" в одних случаях как "оло", а в других как "ала", то это внесёт еще больше путаницы, придется делать множество исключений из этого правила. К тому же разные диалекты языка имеют разные варианты произношения.